# Distance between POINT and GEOMETRYCOLLECTION objects in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, geospatial

MYSQL ver 5.7

**Requirement:**
I have a bunch of POINT geometries in MYSQL table and I have to find all the POINT geometries that are within 5km distance/radius of a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION object.

GEOMETRYCOLLECTION may contain more than one type of geometries like POINT, POLYGON etc.

**Sample GEOMETRYCOLLECTION data:**
`SET @g1 = ST_GeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT (-156.366489591715 66.913750389327),POLYGON ((-156.357608905242 66.906958164897, -156.360302383363 66.9066027336476, -156.361997104194 66.9067073607308, -156.363616093774 66.9066368440642, -156.365477697938 66.9065867326059, -156.368127298976 66.9065970034393, -156.370061891681 66.9066888794808, -156.37182258022 66.9068547305222, -156.373286981259 66.9070724523969, -156.374390675008 66.9072952721882, -156.376359777088 66.9077681138541, -156.377706173961 66.9080113180204, -156.379222192708 66.9081328753119, -156.380729601039 66.9081591586452, -156.382562289578 66.9081211961453, -156.387571662487 66.9099676951007, -156.389320598943 66.9125180930134, -156.389291120818 66.9145787836353, -156.384722634367 66.9167899596735, -156.37955035 66.9195246586276, -156.372520662511 66.9209119638337, -156.360432280238 66.9215118034161, -156.355776993787 66.9203754471679, -156.34906598338 66.9180659711298, -156.347941981299 66.9174007836309, -156.346853913592 66.9167568252985, -156.34605399901 66.9158971169665, -156.346982815675 66.9151925950926, -156.346794497967 66.9144321773854, -156.345642955261 66.9140107294695, -156.343831364638 66.9136152003034, -156.342996512556 66.9130307378043, -156.343113243806 66.9123137492637, -156.343498096931 66.9119029992644, -156.344661664637 66.9111819440571, -156.345080786511 66.9105884961414, -156.345524286511 66.9099605023924, -156.347168040675 66.9098486503092, -156.348952756297 66.9096090419763, -156.348689200048 66.9089614565606, -156.349495732338 66.908706844061, -156.350786711503 66.9082992794783, -156.352211271917 66.9083472388533, -156.353952768789 66.90829894302, -156.355389368787 66.9082072242701, -156.356512531285 66.9079768284371, -156.356677961493 66.9078075857291, -156.356422527119 66.907644261771, -156.355901372953 66.9072802273965, -156.357608905242 66.906958164897)))');`

**Sample POINT data:**
`SET @p1 = ST_GeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT (-156.342840017 66.9320439348))');`

I have tried **ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(@g1,@p1)** spatial function (which returns the value in meters) but it seems it doesn't support geometry types other than POINT and MULTIPOINT.

Then I have used:

## ST_DISTANCE(@g1,@p1)

'0.015301834064271899'

I am unable to understand the what is the UNIT of this returned value in MYSQL 5.7?

I have searched a lot on the internet and there is no proper documentation available regarding the same. In POSTGIS, this can be done but I am struggling to do this in MYSQL ver 5.7.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ST_Distance` returns "distance" in degrees here - i.e. the flat map view of the shortest distance between shapes. This value cannot be mapped to real distance, as real world distance of 1 degree along parallel is different from distance of 1 degree along meridian except near the equator.

Looks like MySQL cannot correctly compute distance here. You would be better served by systems with more geospatial support, like PostgreSQL + PostGIS, or Google BigQuery, etc. They give you correct answer, you just need to replace `ST_GeomFromText` with `ST_GeogFromText` to work with spherical geographies.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the information. I'll look for other alternatives.